# PowerView to PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

Is there a way to export PowerView slides/tabs to PowerPoint?  I realize there are a couple articles on how to [export PowerView from Sharepoint](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh759323(v=sql.110).aspx), but wondering if there is a way to do this for PowerView that lives in Excel.

When I try and follow the instructions in the above link, there is no File -> export -> export to PowerPoint in the Excel file menu.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you are using SharePoint. The following article states (emphasis added);

> There are two versions of Power View: Power View in Excel 2013 and Power View in SharePoint 2013. **You can only export to PowerPoint from Power View in SharePoint 2013.**

([source - Export a report from Power View in SharePoint to PowerPoint](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/export-a-report-from-power-view-in-sharepoint-to-powerpoint-HA102834765.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA102835634))

Note: the article you linked in your question was outdated and had a link to the updated info for [Power View: Explore, visualize, and present your data](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/power-view-explore-visualize-and-present-your-data-HA102835634.aspx#_Toc382586528).